# Add SQL Server extended properties to EF 4.0 model

Tags: entity-framework, poco

Hi
Is there a way to make EF model automatically fetch SQL Server extended property into model? I've read about POCO, but I'm a little confused since it states that you should turn automatic code generation off. If you do that, does your model still update automatically when you add new objects? and how should I update my model so it gets the extended properties for each object(table or column) automatically and sets it in the model?

Answer (score 0):

That's where T4 comes in. You turn off the automatic generation, and can choose a template you want for the objects(templates also generate the objects but according to your requirements). You can use already existing templates, or create your own. To add those templates, just double click on the .edmx, then right click on window, and Add Code Generation Item.